# generated code - code for domain classes as it could have been generated by a tool

Tags: c#, dns

I have seen several samples projects where creates domainObject using an external tool. In the code, it's written in a region:

> generated code - code for domain classes as it could have been generated by a tool

I'm interested about this tool, if this can save much time, I would use it! Which tool might be? I've seen this in PRISM samples.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio generally places that comment at the top of code files it generates.  For example, adding a Linq to SQL mapping will generate a *.designer.cs with the header

```
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.235
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
```

These files are meant to be re-generated when there are changes to their dependencies (such as adding new tables in your linq to sql mapping).